# How to import static class (or static method) into IronPython (or DLR) using C# code(not python)?

Tags: c#, static, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

scope.SetVariable("math", ?? typeof(System.Math) ??);

or do I need create a module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

scope.SetVariable("math", DynamicHelpers.GetPythonTypeFromType(typeof(System.Math)));

DynamicHelpers is in IronPython.Runtime.Types.

Comment: And did you know how to create a ScripeScope that has parent scope?

Comment: There's no way to do this - while Scope's have a Parent property ScriptScope's don't expose this.  The parent property on Scope's is also going away.  If you want to chain lookups you should create a ScriptScope w/ your own custom IAttributesCollection which knows how to look in the parent scope.

Comment: Thank you.I found I could create a Scope with a parent scope using Scope(Scope parent, IAttributesCollection dictionary), and HostingHelpers can create a ScriptScope from a Scope.